# Comprehending the walk through of a recursive code

Tags: c++, recursion, recursive-backtracking

If I keep my hand on each line of code as we go through, then when we hit a function call, my hand goes to the function which is called and that function begins to execute, after that my hand returns back to the line where the function was called.
 Now when it comes to recursion, when I keep calling the same function, how does the hand behave? Is there a new hand for each function call? I don't understand how the code "goes back up a tree of recursive calls". I understand there is a stack. I have seen all those videos explaining it.
 What I don't understand is that if I write cout statements, one above and one under the recursive call, then I understand why the cout statement above the recursive call executes as many times as the recursive function is being called, but then how does the cout statement below the recursive call also get executed those many times? 
Here's an example

```
int Factorial(int n)
{
  cout<<"first cout statement before the recursive call";
  if( n == 0 )
     return 1;
  int F = n*Factorial(n-1);
  cout<<"second cout statement after the recursive call";
  return F; 
}
int main()
{
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 int result = Factorial(n);
 cout<<result;
}
```

This the output below.

```
first cout statement before the recursive call
first cout statement before the recursive call
first cout statement before the recursive call
first cout statement before the recursive call
first cout statement before the recursive call
first cout statement before the recursive call

second cout statement after the recursive call  //Notice these
second cout statement after the recursive call
second cout statement after the recursive call
second cout statement after the recursive call
second cout statement after the recursive call
120
```

Comment: You need to show your recursive code if you want us to help you understand it. Under what conditions does your recursive function return? Without a branch-to-return your code will result in a stack-overflow and will never call the second `cout` operation.

Comment: It's a general question. With regards to any recursive code, let it be Fibonacci or even a factorial.

Comment: Yes, of course, considering all the base conditions are taken care of and a return is below the last ```cout``` statement.

Comment: " but then how does the cout statement below the recursive call also get executed those many times?" - because when the recursive call returns the computer will then execute the next instruction, which is the second `cout` call.

Comment: I have added the code as an example.

Comment: "I don't understand how the code "goes back up a tree of recursive calls"." - the computer **doesn't** "go back up a tree" - it returns to its caller's stack-frame's next instruction.

Comment: A common misconception when starting with programming is that a a function-call or subroutine invocation (the `CALL` instruction) is the same thing as a `GOTO` or `JUMP` but they aren't: the difference between a `CALL` and a `GOTO` (assuming you store the return address in a global variable) is that a `CALL` adds the return address to a list (the stack) so it has a "history" of its calls, whereas using a `GOTO` (with a global variable to hold the return address) you can only `RETURN` once so the stack is what enables programs to return all the way back to the entrypoint function.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the call stack like a tray of index cards. The stack starts out empty. The only things you can do are write down a new index card and put it on the top, or take whatever is on the top off.

There is some stuff in that tray put there by the runtime, but for the moment let's just pretend that the tray is empty when `main()` starts to run.

Pretend that each function is a chapter in a book.  Each page has a bunch of individual sentences that each tell you to do one specific thing.  One of those things could be "go to another chapter and do what it says, using this information I have here."  When you reach such a sentence, you need to remember how to get back to where you were, so you write down the following on an index card:

- What chapter you are currently in and what sentence of the chapter you just read (maybe page number, paragraph number, and sentence number within that paragraph, for example).
- Any of the information you were working with before you were asked to go to another chapter.

You put this card on the top of the tray, then you turn to the other chapter and start doing stuff.

When you get to a sentence that says "you are done with this chapter, go back to the last chapter with this result" then you take the card off of the top, turn back to whatever chapter it says, find the sentence immediately following the one the card indicates, and you proceed from there.

That's all that's happening here.  Chapters are functions.  Sentences are machine instructions.  Stuff you take to the other chapter are function arguments.  Stuff you take back from a chapter is the return value.  The "stuff you were working with" that you put down on the index card is the value of any function-local variables at the time a function call was made.

When you make a recursive call, you still put something on the stack, but you just go to the same chapter you were already reading -- just with slightly different information.  When you need to leave the chapter, the top card might say that you are still in the same chapter, but on a different sentence and with different information.

You have a series of nested calls, one stack frame per recursive invocation.  When control returns out of the recursive call, you're still in the same function -- but with the same local variable values you had before the call.

So in your case, yes, you could think of it that you have "multiple hands."  However deep you were recursing into the same function, you have to work your way back up as each recursive call returns.

There honestly is *no difference whatsoever* between recursive calls and non-recursive calls in the way that the program flow logically progresses (except in the case of tail-call optimization).  The compiler and machine code don't care that the same function is called, it performs the same process either way.

Comment: Ok, so each of those multiple hands comes down, and each of them prints out the " second cout statement after the recursive call". So the first hand pauses and waits for the other calls to complete and that causes the back up the tree effect?

Comment: It's super cool. Do we have to think that deep when writing the recursive code? What do you keep in mind when we write a simple recursive algorithm?  Just the base condition and another else condition? How do we think about this?

Comment: @AkramElectroTech Fundamentally you need at least one recursive condition and one terminating condition. Here the terminating condition is `n == 0` and the recursive condition is `n != 0`. If you really want to have a better picture of what's going on, include `n` in each statement that writes output! That will help clearly illustrate how the recursive call behaves.